# Rank like Subtotals

Tags: excel, rank, subtotal

It's possible use Rank like Subtotals, that only use de showing data?.

If I filter data by a column, I want than Rank function only use these datas

Example

```
A   B   C   The column C its Rank of column B
a   5   3       
b   9   1  
a   2   4
c   7   2
```

Now if I apply a filter in column A for value 'a'

```
A   B   C    I want the rank recalculate with this new data
a   5   1    --> column C change from value 3 to value 1
a   2   2    --> column C change from value 4 to value 2
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, clearify your question and show your attempts.

Comment: Yes I can. When you use the ´SubTotal´ function it is filter sense. In other words if you filter then ´SubTotal´ apply over the filter data. I want to do the same with ´Rank´ function. When filter data I want to get a new rank than aisgn a value only  for the filter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it by using `RANK()` formula, but you can create customizable rank formula. For this, You should add column at the and of table to indicate the row visibility, and put this formula into this column:

```
=(AGGREGATE(3;5;B2)>0)+0
```

Then put this formula into column C:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$9<B2)*($E$2:$E$9=1))+1
```

To check real example, download [my sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1dEZnQXE1UlNzZzg)